# Developing simple Quiz application with Local Sqlite databese but score not incress

Tags: java, android, sql

I am using local SQlite database to get data. It correctly displays in the view, but the score is not increased. Can you see the problem?

```
RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
//problem is here score not incress ...
if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {
         score++;
         Log.d("score", "Your score" + score);
}
if(qid<5){
     currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
     setQuestionView();
}else{
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
     intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
}
```

Here is log output:

04-20 17:32:50.448 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C HP 04-20 17:32:51.648 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: B SuSe 04-20 17:32:52.178 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C RAM 04-20 17:32:52.688 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: A Router 04-20 17:32:53.218 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C Ruby

Comment: Can you provide the log output?

Comment: 04-20 17:32:50.448 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C HP
04-20 17:32:51.648 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: B SuSe
04-20 17:32:52.178 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C RAM
04-20 17:32:52.688 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: A Router
04-20 17:32:53.218 19972-19972/com.example.zeenat.quizappsqlite D/yourans: C Ruby

Comment: (...facepalm)but not as a comment... update the question and add it all

Comment: sir @JonasKöritz this is log result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if the given answer (Letter A, B, C) is equal to the correct answers text. Your code increasing the score will never get called. `answer.getText()` does not return a single letter, it will give you the answers text. `currentQ.getANSWER()` instead will just give you the single letter the user selected.

Comment: how to fix the problem sir

Comment: You will have to change `answer.getText()` to something that will give you the correct answers **letter** instead of **text**